# AWS EC2 vs Serverless Cost Comparison

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am currently using AWS EC2 for my workloads.

Now I want to convert the EC2 server to the Serverless Platform i.e(API Gateway and Lambda).

I have also followed different blogs and I am ready to go with the serverless. But, my one concern is on pricing.

How can I predict per month cost for the serverless according to my use of EC2? Will the EC2 Cloudwatch metrics help me to calculate the costing?

How can I make cost comparison?

Comment: The cost for going serverless is directly proportional to how often the service is used. So you pay for the compute that is used. This is different to ec2 as ec2 pricing is based on hours ran. So it could be a big savings to go with serverless, but that all depends on the workload you are doing.  Especially if you have times where you have low or no use as lambda and api-gateway cost nothing when they are not invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no simple answer to your question as **a simple lift and shift from a VM to Lambda is not ideal**. To make the most of lambda, you need to architect your solution to be serverless. This means making use of the event-driven nature of Lambda.

**Now to answer the question simply**, you are charged only for the time it takes to serve a request (to the next 100ms). So if your lambda responds to the request in 70ms you pay for 100ms of execution time. If you serve the request in 210ms then you pay for 300ms.

You also pay for the memory allocated to the function on the order of GB per/month.

If you have a good logging or monitoring strategy you could **check how long it takes to serve each type of request** and how often they occur. If your application is fairly low-scale and is not accessed often (say all requests come within an 8 hour window) then you may end up saving money with lambda as you are only paying AWS for the time spent serving the request.

Also, it may help to read the following article on common pitfalls:
https://medium.com/@emaildelivery/serverless-pitfalls-issues-you-may-encounter-running-a-start-up-on-aws-lambda-f242b404f41c